# Disconnecting a recordset is failing when setting activeconnection to nothing

Tags: excel, vba, recordset

I am using VBA in Excel 2010 on Windows 7 (ADO 6.1).  I'm trying to execute the code below to grab a disconnected recordset from a SQL stored procedure.  There are no parameters, and if I try to execute this as a connected recordset (server side cursor), the code executes just fine.

The problem occurs on the very last line of the procedure where I try to set the activeconnection property to nothing.  Excel pops up a blank error message box with no error message or error number, just the vbCritical icon.

Does anyone know why an error would occur trying to clear the active connection?

```
Dim SQLConnectionString as String
SQLConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=SERVERNAME\INSTANCE;Database=Database;UID=user;PWD=password;"

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.recordset

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open SQLConnectionString
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.recordset

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandText = sp
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
End With

Set rs.ActiveConnection = cn

rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rs.Open cmd.Execute

Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
```